# Custom Field API with multiple values - form generates two fields by default

Tags: 7, entities, hooks

I have a custom field that contains couple of fields (select, textarea, text). I've implemented hook_field_widget_form like so:

I've added a field to content type and set 'Number of values' to unlimited. When I open a node add page form /node/add/my_content_type this field is displayed twice by default and has option "Add another item" at the bottom. It should be displayed just once. When there are two containers it adds to database both entries for delta 0 and delta 1. This behaviour force opening third container with my field next time I edit the node and so on. Why is this happening?

```
function mymodule_field_widget_form(&$form, &$form_state, $field, $instance, $langcode, $items, $delta, $element) {
  switch ($instance['widget']['type']) {
    case 'solas_block_select':
      $element += array(  
        '#type' => 'container',
      );

      $element['title'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textfield',
        '#title' => t('Block title'),
        '#description' => t('Override block title or leave empty to keep it\'s default value or place <none> for not providing any'),
        '#required' => FALSE,
        '#default_value' => isset($items[$delta]['title']) ? $items[$delta]['title'] : '',
      );

      $element['description'] = array(
        '#type' => 'textarea',
        '#title' => t('Description'),
        '#required' => FALSE,
        '#default_value' => isset($items[$delta]['description']) ? $items[$delta]['description'] : '',
      );

      $element['block_delta'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => t('Block'),
        '#options' => solas_block_field_get_block_options(array('solas_blocks', 'solas_block_field')),
        '#default_value' => isset($items[$delta]['block_delta']) ? $items[$delta]['block_delta'] : '',
        '#empty_value' => '',
        '#required' => FALSE,
      );
    }
  break; 
  }
}
```

This is how I end up: 
[image]